# Jenkins Build and run many test suites

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need help in configuring a Jenkins Job.

Currently, we have 25 test suites for which 25 individual jobs are created in Jenkins and they are running fine. The problem is for each job build from git when it is started. is there any possibility where I can build or checkout code from GitHub once and run all the jobs using the same build. Please do suggest. Also, help with steps if this can be achieved by pipeline job or some groovy code

Thanks and regards
Sadiq

Comment: Yes, this can be pretty easily achieved with pipelines. Use the `parallel` step to run your tests in parallel and the `(un)stash` steps to copy the cloned repo between parallel branches.

Comment: I suggest to close this question as it is too broad. Please ask a specific question, if you're hitting a specific problem with the pipeline implementation.